# How to introduced a new column based on parent and child id combinations in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The entry id is unique and based on point of sale number. I would like to group all the variations of orders grouped by parent & child ID  within a receipt. Using the data below I would like to introduce a new column that would allow me to group the unique combinations of parent and Child Id in SQL Management Studio.

This is my code :

```
SELECT
       [EntryId]
      ,[CheckNumber]  ReceiptId
      ,[ParentId]
      ,[FKItemId] ChildId
FROM POSITEMS
```

Table

```
EntryId |     ReceiptId |   ParentId       | ChildId      
1069869 |     10064     |      0000        | 3010    
1069870 |     10064     |      3010        | 20095     
1069899 |     10064     |      3010        | 20070   
1069914 |     10064     |      3010        | 20040       
1069929 |     10064     |      0000        | 3010     
1069930 |     10064     |      3010        | 20095   
1069952 |     10064     |      3010        | 20090   
1069967 |     10064     |      3010        | 20050
```

The stars denote the two unique parent child id combinations that I would like to group from the result set.

```
EntryId |     ReceiptId |   ParentId       | ChildId, GroupedID        
1069869 |     10064     |      0000        | 3010   , 1 
1069870 |     10064     |      3010        | 20095  , 2     
1069899 |     10064     |      3010        | 20070  , 2 
1069914 |     10064     |      3010        | 20040  , 2     
1069929 |     10064     |      0000        | 3010   , 3  
1069930 |     10064     |      3010        | 20095  , 4 
1069952 |     10064     |      3010        | 20090  , 4  
1069967 |     10064     |      3010        | 20050  , 4
```

Comment: Can you provide an example desired output and anything you may have already tried?

Comment: If you just want to group by unique combinations you can add both columns into a group by statement e.g. group by ParentId, ChidId withough the need for an additional column

Comment: I have added the desired output in my original request.

Comment: The ParentID , ChildId combination is not unique. A person can order the same combination multiple times on one receipt. E.g ParentId 3010 is a CheeseBurger with Onions 20095, Mushrooms 20070 and Lettuce 20040. It could be a family where two kids want the same burger. Thus the EntryId is the only other column that would allow me to make the combination unique but how could I use it?

Comment: @user6516027 -- From the data provided in your question, what is your expected result?  We are presuming your current select statement returns the data you supplied.  Are you just looking for `distinct`?

Comment: i have added a column GroupedID (this needs to be calculated) , this is what i want to achieve to be able to count all the unique order combinations within a Receipt ID. –

Comment: The GroupedID that you provided doesn't make much sense to me. It doesn't seem to follow any concrete logic (at least from what I can tell). For example, why does the ParentId / ChildId combination of '0000' / '3010' have two different GroupedID's, that is 1 and 3? What differentiates the two rows from each other?

Comment: The Grouped Id is the way orders are grouped in a restaurant for customers. On this receipt (10064) the customer ordered two burgers (3010 x2) each with their own toppings Child Ids. I want to be able to extract this type of information from the table but need to introduce some intelligence based on the entry ID to allow me to group in the manner they ordered. The grouped id would be a calculated column. Or if you know of any other way to do this it would be helpful? Ignore where ParentID = 0

Comment: user6516027 I understand your 1 2 3 4 now but @Yobik and I are both trying to say that we are looking for the way to actually get to that grouping for you.  Is their another key that relates the items to a receipt or is it the first 0000 parent is the main line item (hamburger) and subsequent children to 3010 until another 0000 is encountered on the receipt ?  but then I guess why woudn't all of your two's and 1s be the same and 3 and 4 be the same. I guess unless you put in more data as requested several times I am finished assisting.  Try putting in entry names to make more sense.

Comment: there is a unique ID which is system generated this i have excluded intentionally as it serves no purpose, the only other id would be the entry id which that makes the records unique on a receipt. Yes the first 0000 parent is the main line item followed by the children until another 0000 is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

you could  use  concat

```
select concat(parentId, '_', ChildId) from your_table;
```

You obtain eg 0 , 3010

```
0_3010
```

Comment: This would not give me the unique combinations. An example is  I need to group EntryID, 1069870,1069899,1069914 by introducing a unique combination ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      [CheckNumber]  ReceiptId
      ,[ParentId]
      ,ChildId
FROM POSITEMS
```

This is the same as group by below.  Note if you leave entry_id then you will always repeat your parent/child combinations because it is a unique id on the table.

```
SELECT
      [CheckNumber]  ReceiptId
      ,[ParentId]
      ,ChildId
FROM POSITEMS 
GROUP BY
  [CheckNumber]
  ,ParentId
  ,ChildId
```

Comment: This would not give me the unique combinations. An example is I need to group EntryID, 1069870,1069899,1069914 by introducing a unique combination ID.

Comment: That gives you unique combinations of parent/child at reciept level which is what you asked for.  EntryId is unique in your dataset and looks to be the primary key.  So your results would already be grouped uniquely with it in it.  Perhaps you should post your schema and a more exact example of the starting data and the desired results.  Because your desired output data looks more like your starting dataset

Comment: The result set tells me that I have one ParentID 3010 with 5 child id's. This is not what I want to achieve. I want to get each Parent Id grouped in the order of Entry Id. It this case I need to see ParentID 3010 was ordered twice with it's matching Child Id's.

Comment: again please edit your question as looking at what I see from your example data I would expect 2 parent ids 0 & 3010 and 6 children ids.  When you update I will be glad to look at it further but all 3 answers to your question say your intent is not understood so you need to try again.

Comment: I have added a column GroupedID (this needs to be calculated) , this what i want to achieve to be able to count all the unique order combinations.

Comment: Are you missing another key in your data table?  What is the difference between your 1 & 3 or your 2 & 4 s?  It can't be EntryId because if it was then your 2s would really be 2,3,4, 3 would b 5, 4s would be 6,7,8